# Visually aligning a jpeg image to Google Maps in preparation for Photoshop tile cutter

Tags: google-maps, maptiler

I'm looking to add a custom tile overlay of my university campus on top of a Google Map.  What I have is a jpeg image of my university campus layout, and what I'm trying to figure out is how to align it to the existing Google Maps such that I know the top leftmost tile coordinate which I need in order to then run the image through the Photoshop tile cutter script found at http://brokenbytes.info/tuts/documentation/examples/tilecutter.php.

The tool at http://anymap.org/GmapImage2TileGenerator/ sounded perfect for this job, but it looks as though it's only just been moved over to a new server and is proving buggy for me (I enter the image URL of my campus, but then it never shows an overlay of it on top of the map).

Are there any other tools available which can help with visually aligning an image/prepping it for the tile cutter, when the image itself has no geo information immediately attached to it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is probably to use the latest MapTiler (from http://www.maptiler.com/) and it's visual georeferencing functionality.

See the video tutorial we prepared: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJxdCe9CNYg

[image: Visual georefrencing in MapTiler]