# Create maps for maptiler

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, maptiler

I´m actually doing a CustomTileProvider for Android, but I dont have idea how can I create tiles from MapTiler. It ask´s me for a Raster map Files, but Is there any tool to generate this map files.

Answer (score 2):

MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) can process normal images - such as a scanned paper map saved as JPEG or TIFF. You can also create a map in Adobe Photoshop or similar software. See: [Visually aligning a jpeg image to Google Maps in preparation for Photoshop tile cutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815526/visually-aligning-a-jpeg-image-to-google-maps-in-preparation-for-photoshop-tile)

MapTiler opens the standard GIS data formats too (GeoTIFF, ECW, MrSID, ...).

Free geodata (opendata) are avaialable on the web nowadays. For example:

- topographic maps for hiking (USGS DRGs) at http://www.archive.org/details/maps_usgs
- nautical charts for sailing (NOAA) at http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/Raster/
- etc.

Some typical maps rendered with MapTiler are visible at http://tileserver.maptiler.com/:

[image]

The free geodata are available in USA and some countries in Europe from the government websites.

High-quality geodata can be also purchased from various commercial data providers.

UPDATE: MapTiler Desktop application and command-line MapTiler Engine can now also generate raster tiles from vector data input (typically in PDF or GeoPDF format).

MapTiler tools can produce also Vector Tiles (MVT) from ShapeFiles or other vector GIS data - which can be displayed with Android/iOS native GL accelerated components or with client-side styles in a web browser. Maps made with vector tiles can be freely zoomed and rotated - with placenames displayed always in a readable non-rotated form. Look at https://www.maptiler.com/maps/ to see such maps - and create an account to make similar maps like this on your own. ;-)

Comment: Updated - on request ;-)